# SQLAlchemy Core indexing from list within SQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently trying to convert some of my Snowflake SQL code to SQLAlchemy Core python code and I can't quite seem to figure out how to convert indexing an array within SQL to SQLAlchemy Core code.

For example if I have the following SQL query, how could I convert it to SQLAlchemy Core?

```sql
SELECT
    TRIM(SPLIT(CATEGORIES, ',')[0]) AS MAIN_CATEGORY,
    ...
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
```

So far I have tried this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func, select
...
select([
    func.trim(
        func.split(table.c.categories, ",")[0]
    ).label("main_category")
])
```

But it doesn't look like SQLAlchemy is able to convert the `[0]` python part to a SQL code.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it seems they have support for trim, and split, so you could ether try [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html), or [GET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get.html)

```
select 'a,b,c' as a
    ,split(a, ',') as b
    ,b[0] as c
    ,get(b, 0) as c1
    ,split_part(a, ',', 0) as c2;
```

| A | B | C | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a,b,c | [ "a", "b", "c" ] | "a" | "a" | a |

Not sure if/how these map to what SQLAlchemy exposes/supports

Comment: Thanks Simeon, the get function seems to work perfectly with the following code.
`func.get(func.split(table.c.categories, ","), 0)`

Comment: if `split_part` is supported, it makes more sense to use just a single call, BUT if it's not supported, working code is better than broken code...